# If $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ has a distributional derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$, does $(u^+)' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ make sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, bochner-spaces

If $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ has a distributional derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$, does $(u^+)' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ exist, i.e., is $u^+$ weakly differentiable in time? By $u^+$ I mean the positive part of $u$. It is tempting to saying that 
$$(u^+)' = \begin{cases}
u' &: u \geq 0\\
0 &: u < 0
\end{cases}
$$
however this is not particularly rigorous. Does anyone know how to treat such objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positive part of $y$ with $y\in L^2(0,T; H_0^1(\Omega))$ and $y'\in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega))$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889756/positive-part-of-y-with-y-in-l20-t-h-01-omega-and-y-in-l20-t-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This answer is probably wrong.  Please disregard.

I have a note that Wloka's *Partial Differential Equations*, Section 25, is a good place to look, but I don't have a copy handy to check right now.

A possible outline is like this.  Let $\mathcal{H}$ be your space of $L^2(0,T; H^1)$ functions with a weak derivative in $L^2(0,T; H^{-1})$.  First you verify the chain rule that for $\Phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is, say, $C^1$ and has a bounded derivative, we have $(\Phi \circ u)' = (\Phi' \circ u) u'$.  (It may help to verify it first on a dense subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ consisting of appropriately smooth functions.)  Then you choose a sequence $\Phi_n(x)$ converging pointwise to $x^+$ and with uniformly bounded derivatives, apply the chain rule to $\Phi_n$, and pass to the limit with appropriate justification.

### This doesn't work because even though $\Phi_n' \circ u$ converges pointwise and boundedly, it does not follow that $(\Phi_n' \circ u) u'$ converges in $H^{-1}$.

Comment: In my opinion, this is false. Since the mapping $u\mapsto u^+$ is unbounded from $H^{-1}$ to $H^{-1}$ it is impossible to control the time derivative in the approximation process. Please check out my counterexample here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889756/positive-part-of-y-with-y-in-l20-t-h-01-omega-and-y-in-l20-t-h

Comment: @daw: I only just now saw your comment, and your other post, and I will try to take a careful look at it when I can.  When we have sorted out the answer, we probably ought to have this question merged with yours, since they seem to be identical.  My initial question would be that since $(u^+)' \ne (u')^+$, the claimed unboundedness of $v \mapsto v^+$ on $H^{-1}$ would not seem to address the question at hand, since that is not what is being done to $u'$.

Comment: @daw: Oh, now that I look more closely at your example, I see why the objection in my previous comment doesn't apply.  I haven't found any problems so far with the counterexample, so I will try to retrace what I was thinking for the proof I proposed here.

Comment: @daw: Yeah, I think I see my problem.  The product of a bounded function and an $H^{-1}$ function is not necessarily $H^{-1}$.  I will delete this, at least for now.  I want to take a look at what is actually in Wloka and see what I was (mis)remembering.

Comment: thank you for looking at this :)